# json get key names as text?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to find out the key of a json value.

I am doing

```
for(var i in rows){
    for(var j in rows[i]){
        console.log('value: ', rows[i][j]);
    }
}
```

However I want to be able to do something like

```
for(var i in rows){
    for(var j in rows[i]){
        console.log('key: rows[i][j].key', 'value: ',rows[i][j]);
    }
}
```

or whatever
so I can access the key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the syntax for(var i in rows)  i is actually the key so you should be able to do:

```
console.log('key: ',j, ' value: ',rows[i][j]);
```