# get key name from json object

Tags: jquery, json, key

This is almost exactly the same as this question [json get key names as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222596/json-get-key-names-as-text), but that response isn't working for me.

I've got a json object

```
{"userList":[
{"user1":[{"username":"mike","memberSince":"01/03/2011"}]},
{"user2":[{"username":"john","memberSince":"01/05/2011"}]},
]}
```

The only reason I have a the "user1" and "user2" labels is because I'm storing the userlist by userId in jQuery data, and then stringifying it to put it in a cookie and send it in another page. I know, sounds stupid, but I'm just building some front end stuff to prove a point before doing this properly with a db.

So the

```
jQuery('div#userList').data('user1',user1JSON);
```

turns into

```
{"user1":[{"username":"mike","memberSince":"01/03/2011"}]}
```

when using

```
var userlist=JSON.stringify(jQuery('div#userList').data());
```

Because of this, the user info is now a child of the userId, instead of just being a child of userlist.

In order to get the user info, I should be able to say

```
for(u=0;u<userList.length;u++){
   var userInfo=userList[u][0];
}
```

but unfortunately this is just giving me an undefined error. If I use

```
var userInfo = userList[u]['user1'];
```

I get the user info correctly.

So, can somebody correct me as to why userList[u][0] does not work, OR

explain to me how to use JSON.stringify without adding the userid to the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the `userList[u]` returns an object, not an array.

And you cannot access the object properties with an index..

you could try

```
for(u=0;u<userList.length;u++){
   for (var user in userList[u])
        {
          // user is the key
          // userList[u][user] is the value
          var userInfo=userList[u][user];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery each function to iterate.

```
data=obj.userList
jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
  var username=value.username;
  var memberSince=value.memberSince;
  ...
}
```

Comment: For future generations,afifsay has it right--this is how it should be done. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/URSbz/

Answer (score 2):

How about changing your object like this:

```
{"userList":[
  {"id": "user1", "username": "mike", "memberSince": "01/03/2011"},
  {"id": "user2", "username": "john", "memberSince": "01/05/2011"}
]}
```

Then, you can index into the userList array more naturally.  That's probably more like what your data will eventually look like coming back from a database backend anyway.

Comment: I'd like to do that, but I don't know how I can change the structure. When getting jQuery('div#userInfo').data(), jQuery puts the result into a key:[object] (if I've got that right), and I don't know how I can get rid of that. It would be great if I could!

Comment: It shouldn't be hard, using jQuery's `map`. Update the question with a sample of what those divs look like (i.e. where is the id, username, and memberSince, and what kind of elements are those located in?)

Comment: thanks Dave, I wasn't familiar with map. I'll get a chance to try that tomorrow and award you the win then!

Comment: Thanks for the help Dave, unfortunately, I couldn't get map to work in this instance. I'm not getting an array of elements, I'm storing json as 'data' in a single element, so user1's json is in jQuery('div#userList').data('user1',user1Json) I couldn't figure out how to map that when retrieving all the different data objects with jQuery('div#userList').data()  Thanks for the help though, and you definitely get points for introducing me to another awesome jQuery method (if that is what that is called).

Comment: If you'll update the question with some sample markup, I'll show you how to pull a flat object out of it.  It's definitely possible.